# Bitnami mysql docker image - replication on docker swarm

Tags: mysql, docker-swarm

Anyone successfully created a replication group using bitnami's mysql docker image?

Docker and docker are at latest versions.

I am not able to start the replication due to the following error:

```sh
mysql_master.1.wnusvzmnltfe@32g-960g-node1    | 2020-12-14T20:57:40.490733Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22'  socket: '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution.
mysql_master.1.wnusvzmnltfe@32g-960g-node1    | 2020-12-14T20:57:43.350634Z 8 [Warning] [MY-013130] [Server] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'repl_user' host: '192.168.10.199' (init_connect command failed; diagnostics area: MY-001064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corr)
```

here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
  
services:
  master:
    image: 'bitnami/mysql:8.0-debian-10'
    user: root
    networks:
      - one
    ports:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - /home/one/data/mysql/data:/bitnami/mysql/data
      - /home/one/data/mysql/conf/my_custom.cnf:/opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my_custom.cnf:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_REPLICATION_MODE=master
      - MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER=repl_user
      - MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=repl_pass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
  
  slave1:
    image: 'bitnami/mysql:8.0-debian-10'
    user: root
    depends_on:
      - master
    networks:
      - one
    ports:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - /home/one/data/mysql/data:/bitnami/mysql/data
      - /home/one/data/mysql/conf/my_custom.cnf:/opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my_custom.cnf:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_REPLICATION_MODE=slave
      - MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER=repl_user
      - MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=repl_pass
      - MYSQL_MASTER_HOST=mysql_master
      - MYSQL_MASTER_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MYSQL_MASTER_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass

networks:
  one:
    external: true
    name: one-overlay
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I switched to mysql image and it worked.  I suspect some leftover binlog (I mounted binlogs to the host) caused the issue, but unable to verify since I don't have the environment anymore.